# How do these no name companies get rights to use copyrighted characters?

Tags: copyright, business

I see ads for these companies all the time, they seem like tiny companies and all they have going for them is that they make use of major copyrighted characters in their products.

Examples:

https://lampsity.com/

https://lewdskate.com/ (NSFW)

Is there some legal loophole these companies are exploiting that allows you to use these characters?  Are they just blatantly violating the law?  Or is getting these rights just simpler than I'm picturing?

Comment: How can we know what agreements any arbitrary company does or does not have? The answer is "Yes, Maybe, No, We Don't Know, All Of The Above".

Comment: "is getting these rights just simpler than I'm picturing": how complicated do you imagine it to be?  It's most likely just a question of finding the relevant agent and agreeing on a price.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's unanswerable

Comment: in most cases? They **don't**

Answer (score 3):

### Licencing agreements

The company producing these has successfully negotiated a licencing agreement with the IP holder to use the IP. These are extremely common.

### Subcontracting

They have actually been commissioned by the IP holder to make these things for the IP holder e.g. for the IP holder to sell in their own outlets. As part of that agreement, they are also allowed to sell on their own behalf.

### Piracy

They are breaking the law and hope they will be undetected, not worth prosecuting or operate out of pirate jurisdictions which will not enforce foreign judgements.